Is there an object layer options equivalent in Illustrator when placing a Photoshop file?
Is it possible to do the equivalent in Illustrator of Object Layer options? I placed a PSD file into Illustrator that has multiple layers but I want to switch out the different layers using layer visibility. Alternatively is there a way to do this with Photoshop artboards?

No.
Love the feature in InDesign, but there's nothing equivalent to it in Illustrator.
